# How Do You Remove Overlays in SMPlayer?

Tags: video

I'm very new to linux. There's a lot I like about SMPlayer. However, I find some of the overlays very annoying.

I often watch large playlists of many short files. Every time a new file starts, several overlays appear giving information about the lack of subtitles. I find these very distracting.

Worse, when I skip forward with the arrow keys (which I do very frequently), a white progress bar appears in the center of the screen, distracting my view and blocking the picture.

Is there any way to disable these overlays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **View -> OSD -> Subtitles only** in main menu.

About **Subtitle:enabled**, it only appears when there's an external subtitle file (.sub, .srt..). Im not sure you can disable that without disabling subtitles entirely.